# When running multiple javascript functions, only first few work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronous

I want to run a function on click that runs multiple other javascript functions. It works, but only for the first few functions called.

More Detail: I am trying to filter a grid. The "savedSearch" function is called by a button that will then search multiple fields according to your saved search criteria (i.e. filter column A for "Monday", which is in the Model). Each "sub-function" (the "appliedSearch" functions) applies to a different field. The first few usually work (I've tried formatting this many different ways). For example, it will filter columns A, B, and C, but nothing happens for columns D, E, and F.

Note: "applySearch" is the function I am trying to call, "ColumnA" is the field name I am sending to the function, @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnA)) is the variable (i.e. "Monday" in my example above).

```
function savedSearch(e){

            if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnA)) != "0")
            {
                applySearch1("ColumnA", @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnA)));
            }

            if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnB)) != "0")
            {
                applySearch2("ColumnB", @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnB)));
            }

            if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnC)) != "0")
            {
                applySearch3("ColumnC", @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnC)));
            }

            if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnD)) != "0")
            {
                applySearch4("ColumnD", @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnD)));
            }

            if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnE)) != "0")
            {
                applySearch5("ColumnE", @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnE)));
            }

            if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnF)) != "0")
            {
                applySearch6("ColumnF", @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnF)));

            }
        }
    }
```

The "applySearch" functions being called are like below (this works):

```
function applySearch(filterField, filterValue) {

    var gridData = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    var currFilterObj = gridData.dataSource.filter();

    var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];

    if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {
            if (currentFilters[i].field == filterField) {
                currentFilters.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (filterValue != "0" && filterValue != "") {
        currentFilters.push({
            field: filterField,
            operator: "contains",
            value: filterValue
        });
    }

    gridData.dataSource.filter({
        logic: "and",
        filters: currentFilters
    });

}
```

Comment: What does `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnF))` actually evaluate to?

Comment: You should show the rendered output, not the source.

Comment: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ColumnA) << These are just the variables...these work, I'm trying to send a column name and a variable to the applySearch functions...I should have been more clear.

Comment: You should have posted the rendered output, or described what actually happens, the content of your JS console if relevant, the JS functions you're actually calling, etc.

Comment: I'm calling a function that filters a column. Its the same function for each column. It works for the first few columns, but not for the last few. I tested putting the D,E,and F parts before the A,B, and C parts, this resulted in D, E, and F working but A, B, and C not. I will post the code in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: First step:  add some logging.  Putting `console.log(filterField, filterValue)` at the top of `applySearch()` would be a good start.

Comment: Why are you calling the different functions different names? Why not just have one that works on any of the columns?

Comment: I tried using the same names, it wasnt working so I was troubleshooting and someone suggested that I dont call the same function, so I copied the function six times and gave them different names